# Is there a simple and small HTTP static resource server in the Linux operating system?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

Since the absolute path of HTTP and the absolute path of linux files are essentially different, I want to find a software to act as a temporary HTTP server to assist me in web development.

Suppose the name of this software is server. I hope that when I enter a command, it will start immediately and treat all files in the current directory as static resources.

```
$ server --port 8080
```

The port opened by the software is 8080, and there is a demo.txt file in the current directory.

After that, I can ask the file through http://localhost:8080/demo.txt in the browser.

Is there such a linux software package?

I know that nginx can fulfill my test requirements, but for this kind of not particularly complicated function, configuring ningx is not very cost-effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the post
[Simple command line HTTP server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32182/simple-command-line-http-server).

Among the suggested products are
[SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)
and a whole lot of others in the
[Big list of http static server one-liners](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255).

Comment: If you want to advance from this to something with more features (and probably more security), I recommend checking out CherryPy next: https://cherrypy.dev/ (but it is more complicated to use; but not super complicated).

Answer (score 1):

Since nowadays every Linux distro is shipped with python, you can use it to start a HTTP server that will list and enable you to download the files present in the current directory.

Just run:
**python3 -m http.server 8080**

Comment: Just note that PHP can do the same (e.g. `php -S localhost:8080`).